# Firebase push() and set()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing a bit of React code to push text to firebase and I've seen a couple different ways of doing this. I think the difference is set() overwrites the data at location while push will add it to the location under whatever is already there, however I then came across

```
this.ref.push().set({text: text});
```

which uses both, so now I'm a bit confused what that does compared to just set() and push()
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `ref.push().set({text: text})` in the Firebase JavaScript SDK does the exact same `ref.push({text: text})`. It's just a shorthand notation.